# RNPickerSelect - Yup Validation

Tags: react-native, select, formik

I have this `select` in ReactNative.
I have a `Yup` validation that looks like this:

```
const validationActionSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    actions: Yup.string().required().label("Select action"),
});
```

```
const Picker = ({items, style, placeholder, placeholderValue, name, icon}: Prop): JSX.Element => {
    const [chevron, setChevron] = useState(false);
    const {setFieldValue, errors, touched} = useFormikContext();
    return (
        <>
            <View
                style={ [styles.container, style] }
            >
                { icon && <MaterialCommunityIcons style={ styles.icon } name={ icon } size={ 20 } color={ '#555' }/> }
                <RNPickerSelect
                    placeholder={ {label: placeholder, value: placeholderValue} }
                    style={ customPickerStyles }
                    onValueChange={ (itemValue) => setFieldValue(`${ name }`, itemValue) }
                    items={ items }
                    onOpen={ () => setChevron(true) }
                    onClose={ () => setChevron(false) }
                />
                <MaterialCommunityIcons style={ styles.chevron } name={ chevron ? 'chevron-up' : 'chevron-down' } size={ 20 } color={ '#555' }/>

            </View>
            {/* @ts-ignore */ }
            <ErrorMessage error={ errors[name] } visible={ touched[name] }/>
        </>
    );
};
```

When I submit for the first time (`Formik`) without changing the `value` - keep default `value`: `Select action` - I get an error.
But if I select a `value` then go back to default `value` - `Select action` - and `submit`, I get no error.

I checked to see what `value` it `return`s, and I get `"0"`. The other values are `"start", "stop", "restart"`.

I've looked for an answer and found nothing - if there is an answer already - point me in the right direction, else any help would be appreciated.